# JavaFX - Difference between EventDispatcher and EventFilter

Tags: javafx, event-handling

I am trying to understand when to use EventDispatcher in JavaFX. I am pretty much aware of all the event mechanisms of capturing and bubbling. But I am still confused with the purpose of EventDispatcher. Because I can get most of my work done using filters & handlers.

Can someone please explain what is the actual purpose and how to use this EventDispatcher?

Thank You.

Comment: Event dispatcher is usually done by control makers (i.e. API makers). That is the part that actually determines how capturing and bubbling is done. Most of the things that involve events are subclasses of `Node` class, and that class has done the dispatcher for you, so you do not need to do that. Also note that things like `MenuItem` do not extend from `Node` but implements `EventTarget`, so they are some custom event routing there. Unless you are doing something similar to that, there is no need to understand all these.

Comment: @Jai Thanks for the very quick brief explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Purpose of `EventDispatcher`

As the name suggests, the purpose of an `EventDispatcher` is to dispatch an
`Event`. The way it does this is dependent on the implementation. However, the
standard implementation (internal to JavaFX) makes `EventDispatcher` a kind of
"collection" of `EventHandler`s. It is the responsibility of the `EventDispatcher`
to invoke the appropraite `EventHandler` at the correct time. What makes
an `EventHandler` "appropriate" depends on:

- If the `EventHandler` was registered for the current phase of the event
  dispatching cycle (capturing or bubbling)
- If the `EventHandler` was registered for the current `Event`'s `EventType` or
  one of the supertypes (i.e. `EventType.getSuperType()`)

---

## Event Path (or "Chain")

If we focus on the scene-graph, when an `Event` is fired it starts at the top
of the scene-graph (the `Window`) and travels through the hierarchy to
the target (usually a `Node`, but at the very least an implementation of
`EventTarget`). This is the "capturing" phase of the event dispatch cycle. After
reaching the target it travels back up the scene-graph until it reaches the
`Window` again. This is the "bubbling" phase of the cycle.

#### Capture Phase

- `Window` -> `Scene` -> `Root Node` -> `Middle Node` -> `EventTarget`

#### Bubble Phase

- `Window` <- `Scene` <- `Root Node` <- `Middle Node` <- `EventTarget`

If at any step the `Event` is consumed (via `Event.consume()`) then it will not
be forwarded to the next step. This effectively stops the processing of the
`Event` at the desired step in the chain.

The way this path is computed is done by an implementation of
`EventDispatchChain` and the `EventTarget`. An `EventTarget` must implement
the following method:

```
EventDispatchChain buildEventDispatchChain(EventDispatchChain tail);
```

When an `Event` is fired it has a designated `EventTarget`. Since the
`EventTarget` will be at the bottom of the scene-graph the chain is
built from the bottom up. It does this by prepending an `EventDispatcher` to the
`EventDispatchChain` at each level in the hierarchy (using
`EventDispatchChain.prepend(EventDispatcher)`). This is where `EventDispatcher`
starts to comes in.

Each `EventTarget` usually has its own `EventDispatcher` associated with it. The
implementations of `EventTarget` in standard JavaFX (`Window`, `Scene`, `Node`,
`MenuItem`, etc...) provide their own implementations of `EventDispatcher`. In
this regard you don't have to worry about how to use `EventDispatcher`. You don't
even use it directly. Rather, you add `EventHandler`s via the
`[add|remove]EventHandler` and `[add|remove]EventFilter` methods as well as
 he various `onXXX` properties.

When `buildEventDispatchChain` is called on say, a `Button`, the `Button` prepends
its `EventDispatcher` to the given `EventDispatchChain`. It then calls
`buildEventDispatchChain` on its `Parent` if it has one. This continues up to
the root `Node` of the `Scene`. The root `Node` calls `buildEventDispatchChain`
on said `Scene` which, after prepending its `EventDispatcher`, does the same on
the `Window` it is attached to.

At this point the `EventDispatchChain` is fully built and is ready to process
the `Event`. If not obvious yet, the `EventDispatchChain` is fundamentally just
a "stack" of `EventDispatcher`s. In other words, it is a highly specialized
`java.util.Deque` but without actually extending that interface.

*Note: `EventDispatchChain` also provides an `append(EventDispatcher)` method
for the situations where prepending is the wrong operation*.

---

## Dispatching The Event

Once the `EventDispatchChain` is fully built it is time to actually dispatch the
`Event`. This is done by calling this method on the `EventDispatchChain`:

```
Event dispatchEvent(Event event);
```

This has the `EventDispatchChain` get (pop) the first `EventDispatcher` on
the stack and call *its* method:

```
Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail);
```

*Side Note: Unfortunately `EventDispatcher`'s method has a similar signature to
`EventDispatchChain.dispatchEvent(Event)` which may cause confusion*.

*Side Note #2: The `tail` will be the same `EventDispatchChain` throughout the
entire process*.

This is where the `EventDispatcher`s are actually used. Here is the algorithm
used by each `EventDispatcher` as defined by the internal
`com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher` class (Java 10 source code):

```
@Override
public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, final EventDispatchChain tail) {
    event = dispatchCapturingEvent(event);
    if (event.isConsumed()) {
        return null;
    }
    event = tail.dispatchEvent(event);
    if (event != null) {
        event = dispatchBubblingEvent(event);
        if (event.isConsumed()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return event;
}
```

The steps are:

1. Dispatch the `Event` for the capturing phase

   - This invokes all the `EventHandler`s that were added as a **filter**
   - Consuming an `Event` here *will not* stop the dispatching of the `Event` *in
     this step*; but will stop the `Event` from being processed in later steps
2. If the `Event` is consumed, return `null`, else forward the `Event` to
   `tail` and wait for it to return
3. If `tail.dispatchEvent` doesn't return `null` then dispatch the `Event` for
   the bubbling phase

   - If the returned `Event` was `null` that means the `Event` was consumed
     somewhere down the chain and no more processing is to be done
   - This invokes all the `EventHandler`s that where added as a **handler** (which
     includes the ones added via the `onXXX` properties)
   - As with step #1, consuming an `Event` here *does not stop the processing of
     this step*; but will stop the `Event` from being processed in later steps
4. If the `Event` is consumed return `null`, otherwise return the `Event`

   - As with `EventDispatchChain`, returning `null` means the `Event` has been
     consumed and processing of the `Event` must stop

This is done *for each `EventDispatcher` in the `EventDispatchChain`*. The call
to `tail.dispatchEvent` is bascially a "recursive" operation (without it being
"real" recursion). In effect this code walks down the stack (the calls to
`tail.dispatchEvent`) and then walks back up the stack (when `tail.dispatchEvent`
returns). And each "link in the chain" does processing before the "recursive"
call (the capturing phase) and after the "recursive" call returns (the bubbling
phase).

Notice here, though, that at each step it is the `EventDispatcher` that is
actually invoking each of the appropriate `EventHandler`s. **This is how an
`EventDispatcher` is used**.

---

## Implementing Your Own `EventDispatcher`

When extending a class that already implements `EventTarget` then you should only
create your own `EventDispatcher` when *absolutely needed*. If your goal is to
control if an `Event` reaches a certain `EventTarget` then your first choice should
be to consume the `Event` at the appropriate place (mentioned by Jai in the
comments). If you want to alter something about the path of the `Event` then you
might need to provide your own `EventDispatcher`. However, due to the closed
nature of the internal `EventDispatcher` implementations, coupled with the fact
that the `EventDispatcher` interface is limited, you will probably be restricted
to wrapping the original `EventDispatcher` in your own implementation and delegating
when necessary. I've seen this done in other people's code (might have even seen
it in JavaFX itself) but I can't remember the code well enough to give you
examples of this.

If you are creating your *own* `EventTarget` from scratch then you will have to
implement your own `EventDispatcher`. Some things to keep in mind if you do
need your own implementation:

- It must only invoke the `EventHandler`s registered for the current phase (if
  there are to be phases)
- It must only invoke the `EventHandler`s registered for the `Event`'s `EventType`
  and said `EventType`'s supertypes
- It must forward the `Event` to the tail `EventDispatchChain`
- It must only return `null` if the `Event` has been consumed
- It must be **capable of concurrent modification by the same `Thread`**

  - The reason for this is because an `EventHandler` may remove itself or
    add/remove another `EventHandler` while its `handle` method is executing. This
    will take place while the `EventDispatcher` is iterating the `EventHandler`s
    in some way.
- It must "fix the source" of the `Event`. In the standard JavaFX implementation
  each `EventDispatcher` updates the source of the `Event` to be the `Object`
  associated with that `EventDispatcher` (such as the `Node`). This is done in
  subclasses of the above mentioned `com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher`.
  The method to "fix the source" is `Event.copyFor(Object, EventTarget)`

  - Note: I'm not sure if this is actually part of the contract and may not be
    necessary if your implementation doesn't require it.

Comment: Note: This answer is sort of a mess (it was basically stream-of-consciousness) and I might edit it to make it more organized and clear later.

Comment: I think it's a good starting step for beginners to understand how JavaFX processes events.

Comment: @Slaw, Thank you for the very detailed explanation.:) 
My main requirement is to add some customisation to existing controls. So I am extending the controls and adding my additional features. My main confusion is to whether add the event customisation(s) through filters/handlers or eventDispatcher. Based on your explanation I think there is no need for me to consider EventDispatcher, as I want to customize some behaviour changes only.

Comment: @SaiDandem Yup. Do dispatch stuff only when you need to route the event in a completely different manner. If you just want to block events, just consume those events at the correct place.

Comment: @Jai, Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @SaiDandem I'm glad I could be of help :) Also, I went ahead with the edit I said I might do. I believe I covered everything from the original answer and most likely added more information. However, since you have already accepted the answer, let me know if I removed something (or otherwise) that somehow makes the answer invalid/incomplete.

Comment: @Slaw, this looks like the complete anatomy of EventDispatcher ;) I can't expect a more detailed explanation than this. I would suggest to post the answer as a separate blog post so that it can reach more people. Thanks a Ton!! for your effort in explaining.

Comment: Do you have an actual example of such an implementation? The EventHandlerManager that I used in JDK 8 has been removed and I'm struggling on what to use. Basically, I need my own EventDispatcher but it seems like a tough piece considering the listing of requirements you made.

Comment: @Maxoudela Take a look at [this](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1795870). I can't guarantee the implementation is flawless as I wrote it quickly and haven't tested it.

Comment: First of all thank you for such a detailed answer - this is a great work. Can you say, what is the entry point of event handling. For example, I have a `Button` and I have and object `Event(source, target, type)`. Is the entry point `button.fireEvent(event)`?

Comment: @Slaw Or I am absolutely wrong? I will say why I need this - I want to make simple javafx implementation for web.

Comment: @Pavel_K `Node.fireEvent(Event)` is essentially a convenience method for the static `Event.fireEvent(EventTarget,Event)` method where the `EventTarget` is the `Node`. This will cause the `EventTarget` to be the `Node` regardless of the `EventTarget` the `Event` was constructed with. So if you want to fire an `Event` with `button` as the target then yes, `button.fireEvent` is the entry point.

Comment: @Maxoudela wondering what you consider changed: EventHandlerManager was internal api in fx8 and still is internal api in fx9+ or not?

Comment: @kleopatra The com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager was indeed internal API in FX8 but was accessible. In FX9+, the com.sun API are no longer accessible at all if I recall

Comment: @Maxoudela currently, it still is - if you modify modularization by --add-export

Comment: Hum I see, it means I am missing the com.sun import somehow?