# Custom Event Dispatcher - JavaFX

Tags: events, javafx

Does anyone know how to write a custom Event Dispatcher based on the javafx.event package? I searched in Google & Co. but didn't find a nice example.

Have anyone a minimalistic example for me? That would be nice - I tried it a few times to understand it, but I failed.

Comment: You can look at the source code for inspiration. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51015783/6395627

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to realize is how JavaFX dispatches events.

When an `Event` is fired it has an associated `EventTarget`. If the target was in the scene-graph then the path of the `Event` starts at the `Window` and goes down the scene-graph until the `EventTarget` is reached. The `Event` then goes *back up* the scene-graph until it reaches the `Window` again. This is known as the "capturing phase" and the "bubbling phase", respectively. Event *filters* are invoked during the capturing phase and event *handlers* are invoked during the bubbling phase. The `EventHandler`s set using the `onXXX` properties (e.g. `onMouseClicked`) are special types of *handlers* (i.e. not filters).

The `EventDispatcher` interface has the following method:

```
public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatChain tail) { ... }
```

Here, the `event` is the `Event` being dispatched and the `tail` is the `EventDispatchChain` built, possibly recursively, by `EventTarget.buildEventDispatchChain(EventDispatchChain)`. This will return `null` if the `event` is consumed during execution of the method.

The `EventDispatchChain` is a *stack* of `EventDispatcher`s. Every time you call `tail.dispatchEvent(event)` you are essentially popping an `EventDispatcher` off the top and invoking it.

```
@Override
public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
    // First, dispatch event for the capturing phase
    event = dispatchCapturingEvent(event);

    if (event.isConsumed()) {
        // One of the EventHandlers invoked in dispatchCapturingEvent
        // consumed the event. Return null to indicate processing is complete
        return null;
    }

    // Forward the event to the next EventDispatcher in the chain
    // (i.e. on the stack). This will start the "capturing" on the
    // next EventDispatcher. Returns null if event was consumed down
    // the chain
    event = tail.dispatchEvent(event);

    // once we've reached this point the capturing phase has completed

    if (event != null) {
        // Not consumed from down the chain so we now handle the
        // bubbling phase of the process
        event = dispatchBubblingEvent(event);

        if (event.isConsumed()) {
            // One of the EventHandlers invoked in dispatchBubblingEvent
            // consumed the event. Return null to indicate processing is complete
            return null;
        }
    }

    // return the event, or null if tail.dispatchEvent returned null
    return event;
}
```

You're probably wondering where `dispatchCapturingEvent` and `dispatchBubblingEvent` are defined. These methods would be created by you and would invoke the appropriate `EventHandler`s. You might also be wondering why these methods return an `Event`. The reason is simple: During the processing of the `Event` these methods, along with `tail.dispatchEvent`, might *alter* the `Event`. Other than `consume()`, however, `Event` and its subclasses are basically immutable. This means any other alterations require the creation of a new `Event`. It is this *new* `Event` that should be used by the rest of the event-handling process.

The call to `tail.dispatchEvent` will virtually *always* return a new instance of the `Event`. This is due to the fact each `EventDispatcher` in the `EventDispatchChain` is normally associated with its own *source* (e.g. a `Label` or `Window`). When an `EventHandler` is being invoked the source of the `Event` *must* be the same `Object` that the `EventHandler` was registered to; if an `EventHandler` was registered with a `Window` then `event.getSource()` must return that `Window` during said `EventHandler`'s execution. The way this is achieved is by using the `Event.copyFor(Object,EventTarget)` method.

```
Event oldEvent = ...;
Event newEvent = oldEvent.copyFor(newSource, oldEvent.getTarget());
```

As you can see, the `EventTarget` normally remains the same throughout. Also, subclasses may override `copyFor` while others, such as `MouseEvent`, may also define an overload.

How are the events actually dispatched to the `EventHandler`s though? Well, the internal implementation of `EventDispatcher` makes them a sort of "collection" of `EventHandler`s. Each `EventDispatcher` tracks all filters, handlers, and property-handlers (`onXXX`) that have been added to or removed from its associated source (e.g. `Node`). Your `EventDispatcher` doesn't have to do this but it will need a way to access wherever you *do* store the `EventHandler`s.

During the capturing phase the `EventDispatcher` invokes all the *appropriate* `EventHandler`s added via `addEventFilter(EventType,EventHandler)`. Then, during the bubbling phase, the `EventDispatcher` invokes all the *appropriate* `EventHandler`s added via `addEventHandler(EventType,EventHandler)` *or* `setOnXXX` (e.g. `setOnMouseClicked`).

What do I mean by *appropriate*?

Every fired `Event` has an associated `EventType`. Said `EventType` may have a super `EventType`. For instance, the "inheritance" tree of `MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED` is:

```
Event.ANY
    InputEvent.ANY
        MouseEvent.ANY
            MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET
                MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED
```

When dispatching an `Event` you have to invoke all the `EventHandler`s registered for the `Event`'s `EventType` *and* all the `EventType`'s supertypes. Also, note that consuming an `Event` does *not* stop processing of that `Event` for the *current phase* of the *current `EventDispatcher`* but instead finishes invoking all appropriate `EventHandler`s. Once *that* phase for *that* `EventDispatcher` has completed, however, the processing of the `Event` stops.

Whatever mechanism you use to store the `EventHandler`s *must* be capable of concurrent modification *by the same thread*. This is because an `EventHandler` may add or remove another `EventHandler` to or from the same source for the same `EventType` for the same phase. If you stored them in a regular `List` this means the `List` may be modified while you're iterating it. A readily available example of an `EventHandler` that may remove *itself* is `WeakEventHandler`. A `WeakEventHandler` will attempt to remove itself if it is invoked after it has been "garbage collected".

Also, I don't know if this is required, but the internal implementation doesn't allow the same `EventHandler` to be registered more than once for the same source, `EventType`, and phase. Remember, though, that the `EventHandler`s added via `addEventHandler` and those added via `setOnXXX` are handled separately even though they are both invoked during the same phase (bubbling). Also, calling `setOnXXX` replaces any previous `EventHandler` set for the same property.